# cucumber rails -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have created a new rails 3.2 app and my cucumber specs are returning this error -

```
undefined method `path_to' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:
```

When running:

```
When /^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end
```

My bundler looks like this:

- capybara (1.1.2)
- cucumber (1.1.4)
- cucumber-rails (1.2.1)
- database_cleaner (0.7.0)
- factory_girl (2.2.0)
- factory_girl_rails (1.3.0)
- gherkin (2.7.6)
- guard (0.8.8)
- guard-cucumber (0.7.5)
- guard-rspec (0.5.11)
- rails (3.2.1)
- rspec (2.8.0)
- rspec-core (2.8.0)
- rspec-expectations (2.8.0)
- rspec-mocks (2.8.0)
- rspec-rails (2.8.1)
- selenium-webdriver (2.18.0)
- xpath (0.1.4)

Any idea why ? I thought it was capybara but it is uptodate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `path_to` method from [cucumber-rails-training-wheels](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails-training-wheels) gem you should add this file to your support folder: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails-training-wheels/blob/master/lib/generators/cucumber_rails_training_wheels/install/templates/support/paths.rb

Comment: is this the same case when I'm trying to use the capybara assert of

`current_path.should == admin_root_path()`

where `admin_root_path` is a specified route?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In feature/support/paths.rb

```
module NavigationHelpers
 def path_to(page_name)
   case page_name
   when /home page/
    root_path
   else
    begin
     page_name =~ /the (.*) page/
     path_components = $1.split(/\s+/)
     self.send(path_components.push('path').join('_').to_sym)
    rescue Object => e
     raise "can't find mapping from \"#{page_name}\" to a path. \n" + "Now, go and add a mapping in #{__FILE__}" 
    end
   end
 end
end
```

write above code into your paths.rb file